# Why capacitor is taking much longer time for charging than it would by calculation?

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, time, capacitance, electronics

I was studying the charging time of capacitor in a simple seriee RC circuit, with series resistance of 10 M-Ohm & capacitor of 10 microFarad. According to calculations, the should store ~63% voltage in 100 seconds i.e. 1 time constant (~6.3 V for 10 V supply). On the contrary, when I was physically measuring it using the multimeter, it was showing less than 4 V at 100 seconds.

I am unable to identify the exact causes of this much difference between the calculated and measured values.

Answer (score 4):

Your electrolytic capacitor has a leakage current and your multimeter has an input resistance.

First measure the input resistance of your multimeter by connecting just the 10MOhm resistor to it. You will see a smaller voltage than the supply voltage. That is caused by the finite input resistance of the multimeter. The voltage drop across the 10MOhm resistor tells you the current that is flowing through the multimeter and if you divide the multimeter voltage by that current, then you get the internal resistance of the instrument.

Next you connect the capacitor parallel to the multimeter. The voltage will drop to zero and slowly rise to a max. value. Again you can calculate the current flowing through the 10MOhm resistor by the voltage drop between the 10V source and the voltage shown by the voltmeter. Now you know the total current flowing through the capacitor and the voltmeter in parallel. Subtract the current that flows through your voltmeter (now that you know its internal resistance) and you get the leakage current through the capacitor.

As a general piece of advice for electronics circuit design: don't try to realize RC time constants longer than a few seconds with electrolytic capacitors. That's unreliable because the leakage current of these components is not well defined and changes with age and temperature. If you need long delays or pulse lengths, use a digital timer with an oscillator and a divider, instead.

Answer (score 0):

The causes are the following.

A typical input resistance of a digital multimeter set for DC voltage measurements is 10 MΩ. With a 10 V source and a 10 MΩ series resistor, this yields an open-circuit voltage across the capacitor of about 5 V because the two resistors make a voltage divider. The time constant is then about 50 s because the equivalent resistance seen by the capacitor is the parallel of the two resistors. In addition to this, there is the leakage current crossing the electrolytic capacitor, which can be in the µA range at the capacitor nominal working voltage, furthering reducing the steady-state voltage across the capacitor.

Therefore, overall, you should likely expect the capacitor to charge at less than 5 V.